# Proving an infinite geometric sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, physics, geometric-series

I'm having a bit of trouble determining what I assume to be an infinite geometric sum for the following question in part ii.)

I've posted my working below, but I'm not sure how to get the geometric sum in the form the question requires.

Working for Geometric Sum Problem:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Remember that whatever goes up must come down

Comment: Would it then be H + 2(q/100) + 2(q^2/100^2) + ... etc.?

Comment: @GeorgeOrwell Yes

Comment: Don't forget the H factor $H(1 +\frac{2q}{100}+ ...)$ and $H=2H-H$ is handy

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried using the infinite geometric sum formula, but I can't quite nail down the actual sum to the form in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgettingthat the ball first falls with height H, then rises to height $\frac{qH}{100}$, falls with height $\frac{qH}{100}$ and so on.

Therefore, the correct distance must be :

H + 2(S)

where S is the sum of heights starting from $\frac{qH}{100}$.

$S = \frac{\frac{qH}{100}}{1 - \frac{q}{100}}$

Simplifying,
$S = \frac{qH}{100 - q}$

Going back to the original problem,

$H + 2(\frac{qH}{100 - q})$

$\frac{100H - qH + 2qH}{100 - q}$

$\frac{100H + qH}{100 - q}$

$H(\frac{100 + q}{100 - q})$

which is the required answer.

Comment: Ah, right. I had to treat the initial height seperate from the remaining geometric series there. Thank you!